# Selenium/PageFactory: Find child elements using parent element's @FindBy?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm trying to convert my selenium tests to use the Page Object Model (and, by extension, @FindBy).  I have several object definitions like this:

```
public WebElement objectParent() {
    return driver.findElement(By.name("parent-id")) ;
}

public WebElement objectChild() {
    WebElement elem = objectParent();
    return elem.findElement(By.name("child-id")) ;
}
```

Converting the parent object to using `@FindBy` is easy:

```
@FindBy(name = "parent-id")
WebElement parentObj;
```

Basically, I want to do something like this, if possible (I know this isn't real code, this is just a pseudo example:

```
@FindBy(name = "parent-id")
WebElement parentObj;

@FindBy(parentObj.name = "child-id")
WebElement childObj;
```

But is there a way too target the child element *within* the parent element using `@FindBy?`. I need to do it this way because I am targeting specific elements on the page that may share the same name or class name with other elements on the page.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean children of this element in DOM?

Comment: Yes.  I added a pseudo code example above.

Comment: Can `child` and `parent` be in different classes?

Comment: Yes they could.  I decent example might be that There are several tables on the page, And I want to grab the 2nd `li` in the 3rd table.  I need find the table, then find the within the 2nd `li`, but I'll only be able to target that element if I'm able to get the table since all the tables have a2nd `li` element.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do is not easily achievable without writing custom `ElementLocatorFactory`.

Firstly I would really recommend using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).
This would make it easy lot to grab the:
3rd `<table>` just like this: `@FindBy(xpath = "\\table[3]")` and...
2nd `<li>` in the 3rd table just like this: `@FindBy(xpath = "\\table[3]\li[2]")`.

But if you really want to do it with shorter `@FindBy` annotations, you can go for `ElementLocatorFactory`.

```
public class FindByContextModifier implements ElementLocatorFactory {

    private final SearchContext context;

    public FindByContextModifier(final SearchContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ElementLocator createLocator(final Field field) {
        return new DefaultElementLocator(context, field);
    }
}
```

Class with an element that will provide you with the context:

```
public class Parent {
    @FindBy(name = "myTable")
    WebElement table;

    public WebElement getTable() {
      return this.table;
    }
}
```

Its child:

```
public class Child {
    @FindBy(name = "particular")
    WebElement specialTableListElement;
}
```

Usage:

```
Parent parent = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Parent.class);
FindByContextModifier parentContext = new FindByContextModifier(parent.getTable());
Child child = new Child();
// This will look for the name "particular" inside the element with "myTable" name
PageFactory.initElements(parentContext, child);
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach mentioned above works, but if you're using xpath, make sure that your 'child' element has a `.//` in front to make it relative.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write a custom `ElemLocatorFactory`, just use `org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocatorFactory` instead:

```
Parent parent = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Parent.class);
DefaultElementLocatorFactory parentContext = new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(parent.getTable());
Child child = new Child();
PageFactory.initElements(parentContext, child);
```