# Issue with CSS locator select-react

Tags: java, css, selenium

I have an issue with a CSS locator. I have a unique label for the parent, and from there I can get the child that I need.

```
@FindBy(css = "[data-qa="select-Seller"] .select__value-container")
Webelement seller;
public Webelement getSeller(){ return seller; }
```

The class is similar to all dropdowns, so the only value that will change is `data-qa`. Also, sometimes I need to deselect them.

For that, I have an `X` locator.

```
@FindBy(css = "[data-qa="select-Seller"] [data-qa=icon-x]).
```

As you can see, the first part is still the same.

So my question is is it possible to write some method (or any other way) that will change the last part of the locator? I have 600+ dropdowns and creating 600+ new locators for an `X` will make me go nuts.

For me, the best way to do something like `element.click\sendkeys\...\` uses the default part (with `.select__value-container`), but if I will write something like `element.deselect` then it will change the locator, but I don't know how.

I wrote something like this:

```
public void clearDropdown (WebElement element){
        String selector = element.toString();
        selector = selector.split(" ")[8];
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector + " [data-qa=icon-x]")).click();
    }
```

*[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (99c7e4e38147c9f61da0c83c5ef1b992)] -> css selector: [data-qa='select-Seller'] .select__value-container]* - this is why "split(" ")[8]"

But I don't think that this is the right way to solve the issue.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea with your `clearDropdown()` method, there's just a more efficient way to get there.

Seller would instead be defined as the parent, e.g.

```
@FindBy(css = "[data-qa='select-Seller']")
Webelement sellerParent; // probably needs a better name
```

Then you would define a method for each element you want to either get or interact with that is based off of the parent element.

```
public void clearDropdown(WebElement element)
{
    element.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa=icon-x]")).click();
}

// probably needs a better name
public WebElement getChild(WebElement element)
{
    return element.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select__value-container"));
}
```

Now you just call it like

```
clearDropdown(sellerParent);
```

or

```
WebElement seller = getChild(sellerParent);
```

for any parent element you want.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to try to concatenate CSS selectors.

It would be easier if you could define a parent as a `WebElement`:

```
WebElement seller = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa=select-Seller]"));
```

And then find elements inside it:

```
WebElement sellerDropdown = seller.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select__value-container"));

WebElement closeButton = seller.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa=icon-x]"));
```

Note how we are using `seller.findElement` instead of `driver.findElement` for child elements.

---

I am not 100% sure how to describe this in `FindBy` terms, take a look if this helps:

- [Selenium/PageFactory: Find child elements using parent element's @FindBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42140987/771848)

Comment: The reason why I'm not doing in that way - because I have over 600 dropdowns for now. In that way, this will take me to make over 2400 lines of code...